# How can I tell which gRPC server I am talking to?

Tags: node.js, grpc

Preface: There is a project called [LND](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd) that uses two gRPC servers. One starts listening on boot with a WalletUnlocker service. The methods are related to unlocking the LND node for use. Then once unlocked, the LND process kills the gRPC server, and on the exact same ports creates a new server with the Lightning service. (Completely different methods)

I want to programmatically ping the LND node's gRPC and ask it "What services are you currently serving, so I can find out if I need to unlock you and wait, or if I can go about my business with your Lightning service."

Loading package definitions and creating credentials all depend on which service I'm trying to connect to, as the two servers are configured differently, but on the same port... so I assume whatever method I come up with will not rely on the package definitions or macaroon credentials at all. Please tell me if I am wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There may be ways of determining this depending on some specifics of the services and servers in question. If the servers support the [server reflection service](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/server-reflection.md), then you can query that service to determine what services/methods the server is serving. If they do not support that, the next best thing is to simply try to make a request to one of the methods for one of the services; if the method succeeds, you know the server is currently serving that service, and if it fails with an `UNIMPLEMENTED` error, you know it is serving the other service.

Regarding the package definitions in particular, the simplest strategy here is to simply load them for both services, and then use whichever one you need depending on which service is running.

Comment: How can one query the server reflection service in Node.js?

Comment: Currently there is no special handling for that service in the Node library. You would have to set up the client with [this proto file](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/proto/grpc/reflection/v1alpha/reflection.proto) (I think) and write your own code to interpret the responses.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Is there a standard distribution mechanism I can rely on for this or should I just fetch the file from Github?

Comment: There isn't any special distribution system for .proto files, so you should just grab what's there on GitHub. And you should probably keep your own copy instead of assuming that it will stay at that particular URL on GitHub.